# Can Kitty Pryde phase the floor beneath people's feet?

Tags: marvel, x-men

Can Shadowcat touch the floor and have enemy drop down through the floor like there's suddenly nothing under them?

Comment: I dont recall seeing her do anything like this but I suppose it would be possible.  She can extend her power to things she touches so if she touched the floor she could make it intangible.  This would be a bad idea IRL since suddenly making a floor intangible would play heck with a buildings structural integrity

Comment: I have no evidence to support this so not putting it on an answer, but I don't believe Kitty can (or does, maybe instinctively avoiding full potential) phase 'part' of an object, and since floors are almost always parts of objects (whole rooms), this could almost never happen.  But if someone was standing on, say, a manhole cover, or set of planks over a hole, she could phase that small 'floor' and let them drop through it.